# Blazor Wasm Data Protection

Tags: encryption, blazor, xss

Wondering if anyone's got a novel solution to this challenge.  Barring any browser-specific hack, or XSS attack, I believe encrypted data in memory and in LocalStorage is safe from everything but extensions.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

This brings us to malicious browser extensions that have unfettered access to both LocalStorage and possibly memory.

Defenses:

LocalStorage - I would think a layer of encryption that requires a short-lived memory-resident password from the user to decrypt.  Any other suggestions or insights would be most welcome.

Memory - This is the question I'm most interested in.  Can a malicious browser extension probe Blazor's memory (akin to a DOM scan)?  Or is Blazor a separate untouchable region and the chrome extensions only have access to the Interop Javascript?  I know I suggested keeping data encrypted in memory as well, mostly to deter pagefile leaks, but there will be moments when blazor legitimately needs to decrypt/use that data in memory, and that's where I'm wondering if a malicious browser extension can get ahold of it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I believe you mean Wasm doesn't facilitate hiding data natively, but what about access to wasm in-memory variables?  Can chrome plugins access that?

Answer (score 1):

Because you run in the browser, you should assume anyone can read the data. Same is true for mobile applications.

The browser is a public client that can't hold any secrets and you can't know if for example the WASM code is executing in a browser or in some third-party "debugger" that simulates the WASM code.

What data do you want to protect?

Comment: I'm not trying to protect against someone that has access to the computer, I just want to confirm whether extensions have access to the wasm memory.  And after reading quite a bit more on the topic, it seems the consensus is that you shouldn't be trying to protect against malicious extensions because that responsibility falls on the user.

Comment: Agree, you can't protect against it when you run something in a browser or in the computer of the user. You can just make it harder, like using HttpOnly cookies and samesite attributes and other common best practices to make it harder for someone to hack you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep one thing in mind:

Anything on the user side can be accessed by him/her or by **anything** else

Comment: I'm not sure that holds true in the context of browser extensions.  Do you have specific a reference to something stating a browser extension can see wasm variables?

Comment: I think `Http Cookies` just can be referenced by the site that own it. but it still is on the client side